# Excel show data from another worksheet by user input

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I need to find the rows between certain numbers (given by the user) to show them on the screen so it can be printed.

For example: The user enters 104822000011 and 104822000020 as `from` and `to` values. Then I need to search in another worksheet for any numbers that are between these. The data in the worksheet comes from a database. I need to return all the data in the rows that are between the given numbers.

I have very little knowledge of VBA, so if this can be done with worksheet functions, that will be preferable. I have googled and tried some things, but none of them seemed easy to do or didn't work. Can anybody help me out a little here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may do that by copying rows (which you don't want) or VBA. 
And I believe VBA is a good option.

But if the record number is strictly numeric and there are not much data to show, I have a stupid method of using a PivotTable.

You can add a pivotTable which reference to the datasheet. Then drag all fields to the row labels. Then for every field settings, in the layout select "Show item labels in tabular form" and remove all the subtotals. It should now look similar to the original data.

Then you can select anywhere on the record number and select "Label Filters ==> Between" on the Row Labels. And then input your from and to value.

Comment: I must say that really is a better solution, just for it's simplicity! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have your data on the worksheet `dataWS`, with row numbers in column A and data in column B

On another worksheet, you input your values `from` in `A1` and `to` in `B1`

Then in `A2` `=IF($A1<$B$1,$A1+1,"")`, which will display the row number you want to display on this row.

Next, in `B2` retrieve the data with `=IF($A2="","",VLOOKUP($A2,dataWS!A:B,2,FALSE))`.
Copy the formulas in `A2:B2` to the rows below, and you should be set.

Should you want to do it with VBA, you could use the following bit of code (that assumes the Ids in your data are ordered properly). Be also aware that it does not empty the target area before writing the new data.

```
Public Sub getData()

Dim currentId As Long
Dim toId As Long

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim targetIdCol As Integer
Dim targetDataCol As Integer

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim sourceIdCol As Integer
Dim sourceDataCol As Integer

Dim readRow As Long
Dim writeRow As Long


Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' name of the target worksheet
targetIdCol = 1    'number of the column where the ids are to be written (a=1)
targetDataCol = 2   'number of the column where the data is to be written

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' name of the source data worksheet
sourceIdCol = 1    'number of the column where the ids are to be read(a=1)
sourceDataCol = 2   'number of the column where the data is to be read


currentId = wsTarget.Range("A1").Value  'cell in which the from is specified (here "A1" of target worksheet)
toId = wsTarget.Range("B1").Value 'cell in which the to is specified (here "B1" of target worksheet)


readRow = 1   'row at which the data should start to be read
writeRow = 2   'row at which the data should start to be written


While (wsSource.Cells(readRow, sourceIdCol) <> "") And (currentId <= toId)

    If currentId = wsSource.Cells(readRow, sourceIdCol).Value Then
        wsTarget.Cells(readRow, targetIdCol) = wsSource.Cells(readRow, sourceIdCol).Value
        wsTarget.Cells(readRow, targetDataCol) = wsSource.Cells(readRow, sourceDataCol).Value
        readRow = readRow + 1
    Else

        If currentId > wsSource.Cells(readRow, sourceIdCol).Value Then
             readRow = readRow + 1
      Else
          currentId = currentId + 1
      End If
    End If

Wend



End Sub
```

Comment: Well the point is that I don't want to copy it to the rows below, since it might contain op to 200k rows.. that's a lot to copy. There should be an easier solution.

Comment: Copying down is on the second worksheet not the one with your data, meaning you only need to copy as much rows as what you expect/allow the from - to to gap size to be. Whatever happens, if you want to do it with formulas, you will need to have at copy down at least as many rows as the value of (to-from)

Comment: The problem is that the gap size can vary alot too. It could be that they want to see all, or just 10.

Comment: Then it's going to be either this or VBA

Comment: Can you help me with a VBA example maybe? I have been thinking about VBA, but my knowledge of that is very limited unfortunately.

Comment: Are the id numbers of your data rows ordered from smallest to largest ?

Comment: No, they are not ordered. But if that is needed (and probably easier), I can do that.